How to rearrange the list by the number of elements?
list={{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},{1,6},{1,7},{1,8},{1,9},{2,4},{2,5},{2,6},{2,7},{2,8},{2,9},{3,5},{3,6},{3,7},{3,8},{3,9},{4,6},{4,7},{4,8},{4,9},{5,7},{5,8},{5,9},{6,8},{6,9},{7,9},{1,3,5},{1,3,6},{1,3,7},{1,3,8},{1,3,9},{1,4,6},{1,4,7},{1,4,8},{1,4,9},{1,5,7},{1,5,8},{1,5,9},{1,6,8},{1,6,9},{1,7,9},{2,4,6},{2,4,7},{2,4,8},{2,4,9},{2,5,7},{2,5,8},{2,5,9},{2,6,8},{2,6,9},{2,7,9},{3,5,7},{3,5,8},{3,5,9},{3,6,8},{3,6,9},{3,7,9},{4,6,8},{4,6,9},{4,7,9},{5,7,9},{1,3,5,7},{1,3,5,8},{1,3,5,9},{1,3,6,8},{1,3,6,9},{1,3,7,9},{1,4,6,8},{1,4,6,9},{1,4,7,9},{1,5,7,9},{2,4,6,8},{2,4,6,9},{2,4,7,9},{2,5,7,9},{3,5,7,9},{1,3,5,7,9}}

The above is in list format, and I would like to rearrange the output of the list according to this requirement. That is, categorize and display the sets within the list by the number of elements they contain: for example, sets with 2 elements are displayed together, followed by sets with 3 elements on a new line, and so on.
I tried using this method myself, but I noticed that the sets with 5 elements still ended up on the same line as those with 4 elements.
GroupBy[list, Length]



Not the essential, just a typography issue.

GroupBy[list, Length] // Normal // Column




The line formatting is just a matter of how wide your Notebook is and how many sublists of each size there are.
For example by making your Notebook rather narrow your output can have the length 5 subelements start on a newline.
If You have a very short list of triples the triples can end up on the last line of ordered pairs depending on Notebook width.

Try Sort which gives the sorted list:
Sort[list, Length[#] &]
    (*{{1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {1, 7}, {1, 8}, {1, 9}, {2, 4}, {2, 
  5}, {2, 6}, {2, 7}, {2, 8}, {2, 9}, {3, 5}, {3, 6}, {3, 7}, {3, 
  8}, {3, 9}, {4, 6}, {4, 7}, {4, 8}, {4, 9}, {5, 7}, {5, 8}, {5, 
  9}, {6, 8}, {6, 9}, {7, 9}, {1, 3, 5}, {1, 3, 6}, {1, 3, 7}, {1, 3, 
  8}, {1, 3, 9}, {1, 4, 6}, {1, 4, 7}, {1, 4, 8}, {1, 4, 9}, {1, 5, 
  7}, {1, 5, 8}, {1, 5, 9}, {1, 6, 8}, {1, 6, 9}, {1, 7, 9}, {2, 4, 
  6}, {2, 4, 7}, {2, 4, 8}, {2, 4, 9}, {2, 5, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {2, 5, 
  9}, {2, 6, 8}, {2, 6, 9}, {2, 7, 9}, {3, 5, 7}, {3, 5, 8}, {3, 5, 
  9}, {3, 6, 8}, {3, 6, 9}, {3, 7, 9}, {4, 6, 8}, {4, 6, 9}, {4, 7, 
  9}, {5, 7, 9}, {1, 3, 5, 7}, {1, 3, 5, 8}, {1, 3, 5, 9}, {1, 3, 6, 
  8}, {1, 3, 6, 9}, {1, 3, 7, 9}, {1, 4, 6, 8}, {1, 4, 6, 9}, {1, 4, 
  7, 9}, {1, 5, 7, 9}, {2, 4, 6, 8}, {2, 4, 6, 9}, {2, 4, 7, 9}, {2, 
  5, 7, 9}, {3, 5, 7, 9}, {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}}*)

altertnative
GatherBy[list,Length]

